# mysql simple moving average in last N hours

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, average, window-functions

There is a cron job that populates the rate every 5 minutes in the following table, Would appreciate some pointers on how to get the simple moving average in the last 6 hours of the rate column

The SQL table looks as follows:

```
id  rate        created_at          updated_at
1   11478.01    2020-08-29 03:11:28 2020-08-29 03:11:28
3   11481.28    2020-08-29 03:20:33 2020-08-29 03:20:33
4   11485.67    2020-08-29 03:29:53 2020-08-29 03:29:53
7   11486.57    2020-08-29 03:39:50 2020-08-29 03:39:50
8   11507.53    2020-08-29 03:48:10 2020-08-29 03:48:10
9   11515.37    2020-08-29 03:53:47 2020-08-29 03:53:47
10  11496.06    2020-08-29 04:01:06 2020-08-29 04:01:06
11  11499.58    2020-08-29 04:02:49 2020-08-29 04:02:49
12  11490.15    2020-08-29 04:22:00 2020-08-29 04:22:00
13  11509.22    2020-08-29 05:19:55 2020-08-29 05:19:55
14  11491.55    2020-08-29 05:26:34 2020-08-29 05:26:34
```

Comment: Should the difference between created_at and updated_at be 6 hours?

Comment: @ankit jindal there would be 12 inserts per hour into the table, ideally it should get the SMA over the last 6 hours, base on the value and created_at only

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does your version of MySQL support *windowed aggregates*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and a range frame:

```
select
    t.*,
    avg(rate) over(
        order by created_at
        range between interval 6 hour preceding and current row
    ) avg_rate
from mytable t
```

Note that window functions are available in version 8.0 of MySQL only.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT AVG(rate)
FROM TABLE
WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

> The DATE_SUB() function subtracts a time value (or an interval) from a DATE or DATETIME value

You can read details about [DATE_SUB](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_sub/) and [AVG](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp)